# How do I change the default voice of Cortana?

Tags: cortana

Cortana speaks in Female, English (US) by default.

I wanted Cortana to speak in Male, English (India). Every time I change the voice settings of Cortana it says "Sorry, i don't understand you" or "Sorry, i can't speak that language."

Some details of my phone -

Model: Nokia Lumia 1020
Latest OS version

Comment: I really don't think that you CAN change the gender of Cortana.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this in my lumia 1320 mobile.

Required:
 You should have the latest windows 10 version 10.0.10586.494 installed in your mobile.

Go to Settings --> Time and language --> Speech

In that change the Text-to-speech as you needed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the voice selection of Cortana in Windows Phone 8.1 Update (or Update 2).

[Cortana does support English (India)](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/cortana/cortana-alpha) assuming you have the correct region settings on your phone.

Comment: I do not think that it's likely that you will be able to change the gender of Cortana in Windows 10.

Comment: @Thomas I'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently for Windows 8.1 Denim Update, Cortana does not support English(India) language.

However if you want to use Cortana, you can change your language to English(UK) and it will work.